# Is there a way to access message.guild.name in a ready event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a utilities bot and I want it to change its nickname on every server to `<server_name> Utilities` automatically when I run my bot.

Heres my ready event:

```
bot.on('ready',async  () => {
  console.log('|| MaRa Utilities, Console')
  console.log(`    Logged in as "#${bot.user.discriminator}"`)
  console.log(`\nBot "#${bot.user.discriminator}" has been loaded successfully...\n`)
  console.log(`The Prefix Is: ${PREFIX}`)
  console.log(`Bot "#${bot.user.discriminator}" Is in ${bot.guilds.cache.size} guild/s\n`)
  console.log(`|| Logs/Errors:`)
db.get("Prefix").then(value => {if(value != PREFIX){
  console.log('A Dev has changed the "PREFIX" on startup.')
  db.set("Prefix", PREFIX);
}})
db.get("BotAuthorID").then(value => {if(value != BotAuthorID){
  console.log('A Dev has changed the "BotAuthorID" on startup.')
  db.set("BotAuthorID", BotAuthorID);
}})
db.get("TOKEN").then(value => {if(value != TOKEN){
  console.log('A Dev has changed the "TOKEN" on startup.')
  db.set("TOKEN", TOKEN);
}})

  bot.user.setActivity(`DM For Help!`)
  bot.user.setUsername(bot.Message.guild.name + ' Utilities')
})
```

Comment: You'd have to choose a specific guild since the `ready` event isn't associated to a guild. It's simply the client coming online

Comment: how would i be able to code it so the username is different in every server?

Comment: its just i came on here because i was stuck basicly..

Comment: The username? You want to set the bot's nickname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through [GuildManager#cache](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache). Check if the client has permission to change it's own nickname (string constant "CHANGE_NICKNAME") if it does have the permission then use [Member#setNickname()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setNickname)

```js
bot.on('ready', async() => {
   bot.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => { 
      const botMember = guild.me;
      if (botMember.permissions.has('CHANGE_NICKNAME')) {
         botMember
            .setNickname(`${guild.name} Utilities`)
            .catch(err => /* Handle Error */);
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to use `bot.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID").name` instead of `message.guild.name`! [Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.2.0/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds)

To change your bot nickname on server use:

```js
bot.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID").me.setNickname(`${bot.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID").name} Utilities`)
```

So full code will be:

```js
bot.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
bot.guilds.cache.get(guild.id).me.setNickname(`${guild.name} Utilities`)
})
```

Comment: thanks but is there a way to have it so e.g in one server it would say 'Server1 Utilities' and in another 'Server2 Utilities'?

Comment: so it has the server name then utilities in each server its in?

Comment: i dont want want it so its one server that has 'servername utilities' i want it so it automaticly does it to every server its in like every server has a different bot username

Comment: @MaRaGames then could you please edit your question, it's not clear so it is not possible to say what you actually want to do?

Comment: how do i edit it?

Comment: basicly i want it so for EVERY server that the bot is in, it automaticly sets the username for the bot in that server to "(servers name) utilities"

Comment: e.g. 
Kleinste Server: 'Kleinste Utilities',
MaRa Main server: 'MaRa Main Utilities', Test server: 'Test Utilities'

Comment: @MaRaGames Try code from my last edit